# Laravel 8 - How to update the value in one table to another table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

I'm sorry this question might be a little lengthy, I wanna make sure that my problem is addressed thoroughly.

I have a **truck** table which looks like this on the interface:

[image]

As you can see, I have truck number 12, 13, 15, and the number can go on. As for the 'Quantity' column, it represents how many packages is assigned to that particular truck. There's a one to many relationship between the Truck and Package tables. One truck can have many packages. One package belongsto a single truck.

There's a separate Package page exist for user to add new packages and assign the packages to specific truck. Those Packages will be automatically added into the 'quantity' column on the truck page.

The **Package** page looks like this on the interface. It's still empty because there's no records yet, and this is where my problem comes.[image]

when user click on the `New Package Details` button, they'll be directed to this:

[image]

as you can see, the truck number is displayed in a drop down menu, and the values are taken from the truck table we seen above.

When user inserts a new truck data into the truck table, the dropdown list on this create Package is supposed to be updated automatically. I hardcoded '10' into the menu because i was trying figure out how to do it. We should be seeing '12', '13', and '15' on this list. And when user click on the truck number, for example '12', the quantity inside the truck page should be updated as well.

My Truck and Package Model:

```
class Truck extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $primaryKey = 'truck_id';
    protected $fillable = ['truck_number', 'no_of_items', 'postman_name', 'date_of_operation', 'status'];
    
     public function Package()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Package::class);
    }
}

class Package extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $primaryKey = 'package_id';

    protected $fillable = ['truck_number', 'package_number', 'destination', 'date_of_operation'];
    
     public function Truck(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Truck::class);
    }

}
```

My migrations file:

```
Schema::create('trucks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('truck_id');
            $table->string('truck_number')->unique();
            $table->integer('no_of_items')->nullable();
            $table->string('postman_name');
            $table->date('date_of_operation');
            $table->string('status');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('packages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('package_id');
            $table->string('truck_number')->nullable(); 
            $table->foreign('truck_number')->references('truck_number')->on('trucks');
            $table->string('package_number')->unique();
            $table->string('destination');
            $table->date('date_of_operation');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

package's `create.blade.php` file:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('package.store') }}">
          @csrf
          <div class="form-group">    
              <label for="truck_number">Truck Number</label>
              <select name="truck_number" class="form-control">
              <option> 10 </option>
              </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="package_name">Package Number</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="package_number"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="destination">Destination</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="destination"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="date_of_operation">Date of Operation</label>
              <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date_of_operation"/>
          </div>
          
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <a href="{{ route('package.index')}}" class="btn btn-primary bg-danger">Return</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;                        
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-center bg-success">Save Details</button>
          </div>
      </form>
```

Package controller:

```
public function create()
    {
        $trucks = Truck::all('truck_number');
        return view('package.create')->with('truck_number', $trucks);
    }

 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //Validate
        $request->validate([
            'truck_number' => 'required',
            'package_number' => 'required|unique:packages',
            'destination' => 'required',
            'date_of_operation' => 'required'
        ]);
        $package = Package::create([
            'truck_number' => $request->truck_number,
            'package_number' => $request->package_number,
            'destination' => $request->destination,
            'date_of_operation' => $request->date_of_operation
        ]);
        return redirect('package');
       
    }
```

how do I connect the `truck_number` value in **Truck Details** page to the `truck_number` values in **Package Details'** drop down menu list and make the dropdown list automatically updated everytime a new `truck_number` is assigned?

Comment: Why does the `truck_number` column on the `trucks` table and `package_number` col on the `packages` table exist? It looks like you are using them as a primary key. If so, then why not just use `truck_id` and `package_id`?

Comment: @bassxzero the primary key I'm using for both tables are `truck_id` and `package_id`.
Meanwhile `truck_number` and `package_number` are unique columns for the user/system admin to specifically define. The ids are like for the behind the scene database purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to loop through your truck ids to populate a select HTML element.

Try updating your blade to this.

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('package.store') }}">
          @csrf
          <div class="form-group">    
              <label for="truck_number">Truck Number</label>
              <select name="truck_number" class="form-control">
              @foreach ($truck_number as $number)
                  <option value="{{$number['truck_number']}}">{{$number['truck_number']}}</option>
              @endforeach

              </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="package_name">Package Number</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="package_number"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="destination">Destination</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="destination"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="date_of_operation">Date of Operation</label>
              <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date_of_operation"/>
          </div>
          
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <a href="{{ route('package.index')}}" class="btn btn-primary bg-danger">Return</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;                        
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-center bg-success">Save Details</button>
          </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: yay it works! :D but the value shown looks like this:
`{"$truck_number":"12"}`, `{"$truck_number":"13"}`, `{"$truck_number":"15"}` instead of just 12, 13, 15.

and btw, will this automatically assign the package value to that specific truck as well?

Thank you very much btw! you saved me!

Comment: can you tell me why it's shown like that on the interface?
thank youu

Comment: Try `<option value="{{$number['truck_number']}}">{{$number['truck_number']}}</option>` If it works I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Mufidazuhra 問題がない